# Почему не работают рекомендуемые порты в SMTP клиентах?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, smtp

Периодически возникает необходимость в своих SMTP-клиентах (в рамках приложений ASP MVC), задача которых крайне проста - отправить некое сообщение с ящика популярного сервиса (mail, yandex, gmail). Но по какой-то причине, эти почтовые сервисы не работают через порт для исходящий почты, который сами же и рекомендуют при настройке почтовых приложений, однако работают через 587 и 25 порты. Но хочется дать возможность пользователям самим задавать порты, то есть использовать рекомендованные порты, которые они легко найдут в интернете.

1. Как сделать так, чтобы в свои SMTP-клиентах работали нормально через рекомендованные порты?
2. Что это за магические 587 и 25 порты, которые работают одинаково у разных сервисов?

Comment: почтовые клиенты не отправляют и не посылают почту, этим занимаются почтовые сервера. если вы хотите подключиться к внешним серверам, посмотрите как соединяться с ними. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail

Comment: @АлексейОбухов Это я и имею ввиду, мне нужно отправить почту через внешний сервер. И делаю это в точности так же как в листинге по ссылке. Вопрос именно о портах, почему не работают рекомендованные самими сервисами порты, но работают каки-то магические 587 и 25.

Comment: посмотрите полный список адресов и портов. 587 - самый что есть рекомендованный. https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=ru

Comment: 25 если не используется SSL, 587 если используется. А у вас такие умные пользователи, что они лучше программиста знают, какие порты нужны для каждого почтового сервиса?

Comment: @demonplus Про 25 не знал. Это стандарт для всех почтовых сервисов? 587 тоже для всех?

Comment: @demonplus оформите ваш комментарий как ответ, чтобы я мог отметить его как правильный. Если я правильно понял, то при выборе порта нужно смотреть на механизм передачи данных (SSL / TLS) и выбирать порт в соответствии с рекомендациями сервиса.

Comment: @YesMan OK, ответ добавлен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Общие рекомендации:

1. Не доверять выбор порта пользователю, разве что у вас программа для каких-то супер хакеров
2. Использовать порт 25, если не используется SSL, 587, если используется. Это стандартные порты SMTP, можете в стандарте посмотреть.
3. Если с каким-то почтовым сервисом обычные настройки не работают, надо смотреть описание самого почтового сервиса.